# Send Fax with GSM modem on hylafax?

Tags: modem, gsm

I have a couple of questions related to using a GSM modem for faxing.

1. I wanted to know if it's possible to send faxes with the hylafax-server from a GSM modem?
2. If possible can you please explain how one would go about setting this up and demonstrating how it would work?
3. Does this work well? Is it robust or does it work sporadically?

Answer (score 0):

I would try your question on the HylaFax website. They have a forum where others have apparently been asking similar questions regarding this setup. In looking through the questions it did not seem like this was very usable, but I would still encourage you to ask this question there.

- [HylaFax mainsite](http://www.hylafax.org/content/Main_Page)
- [HylaFax Support links](http://www.hylafax.org/content/Support)

Comment: I have submitted my question but I have zéro feedback... Nobody has tested ? Thanks you slm for your help.